# JPA duplicate entries

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, completable-future

I have a Service where records are passed from another service layer, and from the uploaded records need to manipulate them and create entries to a table(Entity: A), in order to keep uniqueness need to validate them by Date, Name, etc.  I use the JPA method findByNameAndDate if available reuse to update the data if not create a new record.

Since this process tends to have more than 1k records, I have made this an async process to speed up the process.  Due to multithreading when multiple requests come in, it creates duplicate records, when there was no async earlier it didn't create any duplicate.

I have used the below to apply the async.

> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->...)

and then add the completable future to a list and get the result, once all the processes are done I return the result.

```
CompletableFuture<List<List<A>>> listCompletableFuture = FutureUtil.allOf(futures);
        try {
            result = listCompletableFuture.get().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How should I fix this issue during async as well?.
FYI:  I even flush whenever the save operation happens, like `saveAllAndFlush` and `flush` methods from JPA

Comment: I don't understand the question exactly. You have an issue with asynchronously checking a Name/Date pair - are you asking us to list out what options you have in ensuring they are unique? If you must ensure they are unique, have you thought about using them as the entity ID instead - when you call merge, JPA will check the DB to see if they exist and perform an update or insert appropriately for you. Otherwise, you are stuck - you already know the only solution is synchronizing the processing of input. If that isn't acceptable, the best you can do is catch the errors and retry

Comment: My question is simple when an object is saved, I check whether the object is unique or not when creating by Name and Date, by these combinations, data should be unique. This works perfectly when the code is synchronous process, but when I make this process as async since loads of object will be sent to this process, this needs to be quick.  When async applied the duplicate validation does not happen correctly it ends up duplicate, since multiple records are being processed asycn process.

Comment: That seems so simple then.. Asynchronous validation from what exactly? You will ALWAYS have a window with asynchronous processes if you are validating and then inserting as another process can be validating a similar record before your insert. The only way to prevent that is by synchronizing it. 3 options: they all get done one at a time on the same process, or you slow things down with pessimistic locking at the database level. 3rd is to handle the exceptions after the fact, optimistic that conflicts aren't likely and you can just retry the operation.